# Showing just one image at the time from database (Swift and Firebase)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

First of all, I am new in this, so please do not make fun of me :)

Basically, I am trying to show and Image of a product but if the client refuses the product this item will not appear on his account. That is why I am creating another table Rejected (setAcceptedOrRejected) where I put the ID of the product and the Id of the client so I wont see the item he rejected before.

What I tried here it was to get the List (Good) with all the items and the (Bad) with the rejected items. Then compare it to display the picture of the item again.

My problem is that I want to show only 1 picture at the time, if the client refuses then it will show the next one and so on but it wont show that picture again.

I hope you can really help me with this one.

Thank you

```
func updateImage() {

    createListProductsBad ()

    var badnot = ""

    for bad2 in listProductsBad{
    badnot = bad2

    }


   Database.database().reference().child("Products").child(bad2)queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

        let userInfo = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary

        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: profileUrl)
        storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
                let image = UIImage(data: data as Data)
                self.productPhoto.image = image

            }
            catch _ {
                print("error")
            }




        })

    })


}

    func setAcceptedOrRejected() {

    let notThankyou  = [                  "ProductID": ProductId,
                                          "UserID": userUID
        ] as [String : Any]
    self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
    self.refProducts.child("Rejected").childByAutoId().setValue(notThankyou)
}

    func createListProductsGood () {

    Database.database().reference().child("Products").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

        if !snapshot.exists() { return }



        let userInfo = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary

        let goodID = String(snapshot.key)


        for prod in self.listProductsBad{

            if (prod == goodID){
                print("Not good **********************")

            }else{

                if (goodID != "" ){
                    self.listProductsGood.append(prod)
                }


            }


         }
    })

}


   func createListProductsBad () {

Database.database().reference().child("Rejected").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

    let userInfo = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
    let currentID = userInfo["UserID"] as! String
    let badProduct = userInfo["ProductID"] as! String

    if (self.userUID == currentID ){

       self.listProductsBad.append(badProduct)

    }
})

    }
```

}

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? Finding the logic and code to do what you've asked? You basically need a node in firebase to for all the values and rejected values. When you load the datasource of items the users can see grab both of these nodes and remove any `key` from the rejected datasource with the full one.

Comment: @Torewin do you have any website that can help me with this. (For the nodes). I tried doing it with an array and for loop but it didn’t work.

Comment: No website but I can help you write it. Give me a screenshot of your firebase nodes with a node filled with rejected and a node filled with available.

Comment: @Torewin like this? By nodes you meant that? https://ibb.co/kwdfkw

Comment: Yup! So let me whip up something - this may take a few revisions to get it exactly how you want so just base with me. First, I am just going to post the code that will be able to have a NSDictionary of keys that the user will see. I don't know your plan for this but you can either have new items added to the list of available things and everytime one is rejected it's just deleted or you can have a rejected list as well.

Comment: @Torewin you are the best! This is my whole class. https://jpst.it/17fGs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158638/discussion-between-torewin-and-keneth-walters).

Answer (score 0):

```
 //These can also be swift's dictionaries, [String: AnyObject] or possibility arrays if done correctly. All depends on your style of programming - I prefer NSDictionaries just because.

let availableKeys: NSMutableDictionary = [:]
let rejectedKeys: NSMutableDictionary = [:]

//Might be a better way for you. Depends on what you are looking for.
func sortItems2() -> NSMutableDictionary{
    for rejKey in rejectedKeys.allKeys{
        //Removes if the rejected key is found in the available ones
        availableKeys.remove(rejKey)
    }
    return availableKeys
}
```